# Azure Web App Deployment: SQLAlchemy OperationalError with SQL Server Connection for Python Flask Application

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying a Python Flask Application to Azure for the first time (free version). I have a Python Flask application that connects to a SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy. The connection to the database and tables happen as the website is loading. Locally, this runs perfectly. However, when I deploy the application to an Azure Web App, I encounter a connection timeout issue when trying to connect to the SQL Server. The application fails with an OperationalError indicating a login timeout expired. Below is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/8dc4e3d6e3306fa/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  ...
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This issue only occurs when the application is deployed to Azure, and not when running locally. Here are some specifics about the environment and configuration:

Environment: Azure Web App
Database: SQL Server
Connection Method: SQLAlchemy using pyodbc as the driver
Versions of dependencies in requirements.txt file:

- cnos-connector==0.1.9
- pyodbc==5.1.0
- SQLAlchemy==2.0.28
  Error: Login timeout expired

I have confirmed that the application connects to the database successfully from my local environment, so it seems like an issue specific to the Azure deployment.

Here is how I'm setting up the SQLAlchemy engine in my application:

```
user = os.environ["User_Name"]
password = os.environ["Password"]
hostName = os.environ["hostName"]
port = os.environ["port"]
db = os.environ["database"]
db_context = os.environ["context"]

# Establishing the database connection URI
database_uri = f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{hostName}:{port}/{db}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
engine = create_engine(database_uri)
```

The environment variables are all properly spelt and correctly added to my Azure web app as environment variables under app settings.

I've tried increasing the connection timeout parameter (albeit I could try an even larger number). When run locally, the loading of the flask app takes about 20-35 seconds due to the database connection and queries I run to set things up. For more context/info here is the startup command used for the flask app:

`gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:app`

I've checked and confirmed that the application works locally and that the environment variable names all match with what I have written on the Azure web app dashboard. I have not tried adding a connection string within the web app dashboard as I don't think that would help since the app works perfectly locally. Furthermore, the SQL server is up and running smoothly for myself and others.

UPDATE:

- I have added VNet integration to the web app and it should be able to communicate with the SQL Server without any issues, yet I am still getting the same error. I have confirmed that the environment variables are correct (all capitalized), and I use `os.environ['var1']` to grab them in my code. The website must connect to the SQL database/server right as the page as being loaded (the page must be loaded in with a parameter that is passed on to a query of the db in the future) so I also set all the environments for the connection string in my environment variables as deployment slot settings. There is a default page that the application is meant to redirect to if the parameter is missing.

Furthermore, these are the latest error logs:

```
2024-03-29T13:31:08.492306143Z [2024-03-29 13:31:08 +0000] [78] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
```

2024-03-29T13:31:08.494285752Z [2024-03-29 13:31:08 +0000] [78] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (78)
2024-03-29T13:31:08.495537458Z [2024-03-29 13:31:08 +0000] [78] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2024-03-29T13:31:08.513749140Z [2024-03-29 13:31:08 +0000] [79] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 79

2024-03-29T13:40:20.623Z ERROR - Container remi2_1_322f8881 for site remi2 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 600.4550416 sec
2024-03-29T13:40:20.631Z ERROR - Container remi2_1_322f8881 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 1433, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-03-29T13:40:20.675Z INFO  - Stopping site remi2 because it failed during startup.

I'm a beginner to this so I am not sure what to do. I increased the startup time for the web app from 230 to 600 seconds and its still timing out.

Comment: Are you sure those environment variable names are correct? The key names supplied to Python's `os.environ[...]` are usually case-sensitive and these are usually uppercase on the host operating systems. i.e.: `python -c "import os; print(os.environ['pwd']);"` would fail with `raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'pwd'` whereas `python -c "import os; print(os.environ['PWD']);"` would successfully print `/Users/FooBarBaz`.

Comment: _3. Is it possible that the website doesn't have access to the database/server, but my local device does?_ Yes, that's entirely possible. Azure SQL databases can have firewall rules applied to them just like any other service. Is it possible that you're company's public IP address(es) are granted access but your web application is not?

Comment: You can always debug by hardcoding correct address first

Comment: Additional Configurations or Settings in Azure:Check the firewall settings in Azure SQL Server. Ensure that Azure services and resources are allowed to access the SQL Server. You can configure this in the Azure portal under the Firewall settings of your SQL Server. Make sure the credentials (username and password) you're using to connect to the SQL Server are correct and have the necessary permissions. Verify that the Azure Web App has network connectivity to the SQL Server. You can try pinging the SQL Server from within the Azure Web App's environment.

Comment: VNet integration allows your Azure Web App to access resources in your virtual network. If your SQL Server is hosted within a virtual network and access to it is restricted, you may need to set up VNet integration for your Azure Web App. This would allow the Web App to communicate with resources within the virtual network, including the SQL Server.

Comment: @Ahad Anjum Python, [Flask](https://onexception.dev/news/1072511/flask-azure-sql-connection) and [Azure SQL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/building-rest-api-with-python-flask-and-azure-sql/ba-p/1056637)

Comment: @Sampath, I added Vnet integration and that part seems to be good. I also made sure all environment variables are capitalized. I am now getting a timeout error were its exceeding the maximum timeout where the container did not start within the expected time (i even increased the time for this). I added an update above if that helps